# MySQL cross-selection limitation issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

T1 has one column which has 9000 unique records (varchar).

T2 has many columns with upwards of 1 million records. One of the columns `T2.x` of T2 has data from T1's column `T1.x`, however some T2 records have in their column `T2.x` data that doesn't exist in T1's column `T1.x`.  `T2.x` is also able to be NULL.

I want to list all records of T2, where T2.x has a record that matches T1.x

```
I tried = SELECT t1.column_x, t2.* from t1, t2 WHERE x = t1.x
```

However, this only lists 9000 records disregarding the many others that exist in T2.

How can I achieve what I seek?

```
e.g.

**t1 [x]
===**
a
b
c

**t2
===**     [x]
1 .. .. .. a
2 .. .. .. b
3 .. .. .. eee
4 .. .. .. NULL
5 .. .. .. c
6 .. .. .. a
7 .. .. .. c
```

I want to get: 1-2-5-6-7

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply the following will work, though it will cause performance issues on that size of table considering both `x` columns are VARCHAR.

```
SELECT
    t2.*
FROM t2
INNER JOIN t1
ON t1.x = t2.x
```

Do you have an index on the `x` column already in both `t1` and `t2`, as if so that would help improve query speed.  I would recommend NOT running this query in a production environment.  If unavoidable, I would have to recommend including `LIMIT 10` (or however many rows you need) in order to limit the impact.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly. This will be used solely for development purposes. I am reshaping a large database. If you have the chance, could you please tell, if I want to do select count(), how can I do it with this query? I tried but it gave an error, just out of curiosity. Thank you.

Comment: `SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM t2
INNER JOIN t1
ON t1.x = t2.x` would return just the number of rows total (as long as you don't ask for any field data)